# cancelled cp + du between ntfs drives caused data loss?

Tags: data-recovery, file-copy, ntfs, external-hdd

I am using Mac OSX and working with two external NTFS hard drives (HD1, HD2) using the Mounty tool to mount them in read+write mode. I needed to move two large folders from HD1 to HD2.

I opened one terminal in HD1 at `/Volumes/HD1/my/source/path`, where I started a `cp -r my_folder /Volumes/HD2/my/dest/path/` command.

Meanwhile, I opened a terminal at `/Volumes/HD2/my/dest/path/` and started monitoring the process with `du -sh my_folder`. Now, each time I issued such command, I would get a `cp: my_folder/my_file_N: Input/output error` message in the first terminal, so I decided to CMD+C in the first terminal to stop the copy, and start again without monitoring the process. Before restarting the copy, I checked the destination folder, and it was showing some corrupted (smaller) files. Therefore, I deleted the destination folder: not via the terminal, but by CMD+del in the file browser - yes, I am sure that I did that in the destination location :)

I went back to my first terminal and issued the same `cp` command again - except that it finished instantly. So I go to check: my `my_folder` is empty, both in HD1 and in HD2. It `ls`'s as empty and shows as empty in the file browser.

Could someone please:

1. explain me what happened? (not neglecting the question whether there indeed is a clash between moving data and the `du` command)
2. suggest me how to recover these data?

Note that for the time being I am too scared of doing something irreversible, so I haven't tried unmounting / remounting my drives yet... A `df -h .` in HD1 reveals exactly the same used / unused space as before this nasty business, so I do hope I can get these files back.

Comment: You're highly unlikely to get an answer. Something is wrong with your system - files mustn't disappear into the thin air just by copying them. Either you've deleted them or something else did (application? malware?). As for recovering, one of the best application in my experience is R-Studio: https://tinyurl.com/r-studio

Comment: At a glance it looks like Mounty is single threaded. Could be worth pinging the developer(s) a question

Comment: @roaima I do not have enough reputation to add mounty as a tag.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov thanks, but unfortunately 80$ is not an option for me. It would really help to find a way to understand what happened. Coming from linux, I am not too used to Mac OSX (~3 years) but I thought that malwares are not too common there. Besides, all I did are simple bash / file manager operations.

Comment: Malware indeed is common on MacOS since the OS is quite popular specially in the US. Again, no idea what has happened but it's quite unlikely that you did it unless you accidentally typed `rm` or `mv`.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Ok. However what does a malware have to gain from deleting my files after an interrupted `cp` command? EDIT - no, I definitely used `cp` only. No moving nor removing.

Comment: Malware encrypting your files and seeking extortion has been quite common over the past five years. I'm not suggesting it's the case.

Comment: elgicse, I'm not sure why you're telling me you can't create a tag. I suggested you contact the developer(s).

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the events would be: the source disk detected an error, which was reported as the input/output error you saw.

Because of the error, the NTFS driver either attempted to unmount the filesystem or went into some sort of safeguard state that blocks any further operations on the filesystem that contains the error.

And it turns out the integration of the NTFS driver into MacOS is apparently less than perfect: maybe MacOS doesn't have a fully equivalent concept of a filesystem reacting in this way to an error condition, or a request for a directory listing now also results in an error because of the driver's current state, and the OS assumes the error to mean the directory is empty.

[The webpage of the Mounty.app](https://mounty.app/) seems to indicate this is not entirely unknown behavior:

> Suddenly all my files disappeared - please help!
>
> This is usually happen when not all files are written properly due to an unmount operation not finishing. The NTFS partition might be marked as "dirty" and the Apple NTFS driver cannot recover from that situation. Mounty will not delete anything by itself, please try to restore your files on a Windows PC using usual recovery s/w, i.e. chkdsk command line utility or professional tools like GetDataBack for Windows. If you do not own any Windows you can use tools for macOS that can deal with NTFS partition maintenance, like Paraogn Harddisk Manager or Tuxera Disk Manager.

In your case though, the error condition was not triggered by an unfinished unmount but by a disk read error (unless the read error caused the NTFS driver to decide to unmount the disk on its own?). However, the resulting behavior seems to be similar.

I would assume that **this could be a first sign of your HD1 starting to fail**, so I would first attempt to make a disk image of HD1 onto some other, known-good media, in case further attempts to use the disk make the problem worse. Then I would follow the recommendation quoted above: get the disk to a Windows system and use native Windows tools to try and recover the data.

I would also carefully check the HD1 disk before trusting it again: [this question on AskDifferent.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/135565) seems to have some suggestions on tools you might use for checking the SMART diagnostics of the disk, although the question is rather old.

(If someone knows more up-to-date tools for accessing SMART diagnostics on MacOS, feel free to edit or chime in!)